# ¿Como accedo a un @app.route desde otro app.route? Flask

Tags: python, flask

Estoy con una duda. Quiero que, en caso que se cumpla **user[0].Tipo == 'Mozo'**, se redirija a la ruta 'mozo', ya que en esa URL tengo varias utilidades que necesito poder accesarlas facilmente, en vez de tener que iniciar sesion para poder usar las funcionalidades..

Con el codigo como está, se ejecuta la URL login_incorrecto, cuando en realidad los datos que estoy introduciendo son los del mozo y deberia entrar. Que tendria que cambiar para que funcione?

```
def bienvenida():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            if request.form['DNI'] and request.form['Clave']:
                user= Usuarios.query.filter_by(DNI= request.form['DNI'])
                contrasena= hashlib.md5(bytes(request.form['Clave'], encoding='utf-8'))  
                if contrasena.hexdigest() == user[0].Clave and user:
                    if user[0].Tipo == 'Mozo':
                        self.mozo()
                    else:
                        return render_template('cocinero.html')
            else:
                return render_template('login_incorrecto.html')
        except:
            return render_template('login_incorrecto.html')
        
        
@app.route('/mozo', methods= ['POST', 'GET'])
def mozo(self):
    return render_template('mozo.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usas la funcion `redirect`

```py
# La importas desde flask
# from flask import redirect

def bienvenida():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            if request.form['DNI'] and request.form['Clave']:
                user= Usuarios.query.filter_by(DNI= request.form['DNI'])
                contrasena= hashlib.md5(bytes(request.form['Clave'], encoding='utf-8'))  
                if contrasena.hexdigest() == user[0].Clave and user:
                    if user[0].Tipo == 'Mozo':
                        self.mozo()
                        redirect("/mozo")
                    else:
                        return render_template('cocinero.html')
            else:
                return render_template('login_incorrecto.html')
        except:
            return render_template('login_incorrecto.html')
        
        
@app.route('/mozo', methods= ['POST', 'GET'])
def mozo(self):
    return render_template('mozo.html')
```